# how to use a function with parameters that are implemented in a model in eloquent laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

- 

I want to use this function `peut_acceder()` that is stocked in the model to check if the user has the right to see the row like a where condition, for each row the function will return true or false, and the function work 100% cause I already used it.

```
use App\Models\Cl_remboursement as Remboursement;

$data = Remboursement::from('cl_remboursements AS r')
                    ->where('r.etat',2)
                    ->join('users As u', 'u.id', '=', 'r.user_id')
                    ->join('cl_adherents As a', 'a.id', '=', 'r.cl_adherent_id')
                    ->join('users As ue', 'a.creater_id', '=', 'ue.id')
                    ->select('r.id',DB::raw('CONCAT(r.nom," ",r.prenom) as beneficiaire') ,'r.type','r.date_soins','r.created_at',DB::raw('CONCAT(u.nom," ",u.prenom) as collaborateur') ,DB::raw('CONCAT(a.nom," ",a.prenom) as adherent'),'ue.entreprise as client')
                    ->with(['peut_acceder' => function($query) use ($user) 
                    }])
                    ->skip($start)->take($pageSize)->get();
```

- 

And I have the model `Cl_rembourssement` with the function `peut_acceder(User $user)`, and in the model function, I get an error because of `->createur` who is not working in this case.
I tried it I just removed the user from parameters and used a variable,
`$user= Auth::user();` I got this error Trying to get property `creature` of non-object.

```
 public function peut_acceder(User $user)
    {
        $acces = true;


        $clientUsers = $this->cl_adherent->createur->gestionnaires()->get();

        $policeUsers = $this->cl_adherent->cl_police->gestionnaires()->get();

        $adherentUsers = $this->cl_adherent->gestionnaires()->get();

        // adherent not null
        if (
            $this->cl_adherent->acces != null && !$adherentUsers->contains('id', $user->id)
            && !$policeUsers->contains('id', $user->id)
            && !$clientUsers->contains('id', $user->id)
        ) {

            $acces = false;
        }

     

        if (
            $this->cl_adherent->cl_police->acces != null && !$adherentUsers->contains('id', $user->id)
            && !$policeUsers->contains('id', $user->id)
            && !$clientUsers->contains('id', $user->id)
        ) {
            $acces = false;
        }



        // client not null 


        if (
            $this->cl_adherent->createur->acces != null && !$adherentUsers->contains('id', $user->id)
            && !$policeUsers->contains('id', $user->id)
            && !$clientUsers->contains('id', $user->id)
        ) {
            $acces = false;
        }


        return $acces;
    }
```

Comment: >with(['peut_acceder' => function($query) use ($user)  }])  ????  where do you see this syntax?

Comment: i didnt understand ur question the function peut_acceder is defined in the model i want to use it foreach element of my table i can get all the element and than use the function but it will take to much time because i got like 45k row in the table the function peut_acceder() test if the user have access it work like a filter i hope u get what i want to say :D